# Insert array as template based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have built a few templates of differing rows (same columns) that I want to be pulled in and inserted based on changing a cell value.

So if you change A1 to value of temp1 it will insert rows/values of the "temp1" template array (100 rows) from another sheet, and if you change A101 to value of temp2 it will insert rows/values of the "temp2" template array (25 rows) from another sheet.

Comment: [Okay](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You'll probably want to look into the `Worksheet Change` event.

Answer (score 0):

You asked to insert rows, not to clean up the sheet and then paste the rows.

The attached Worksheet_Change even code is an example of how to accomplish what you are specifying ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim srcSht As Worksheet
Dim lstRow As Long, lstCol As Long
Dim srcRng As Range
Dim tarRng As Range
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Set tarRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    If Target.Value = "temp1" Then Set srcSht = Worksheets("Shtemp1")
    If Target.Value = "temp2" Then Set srcSht = Worksheets("Shtemp2")
    If srcSht Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    lstRow = srcSht.Range("A" & srcSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set srcRng = srcSht.Range(srcSht.Cells(1, 1), srcSht.Cells(lstRow, 1))
    srcRng.EntireRow.Copy
    tarRng.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
End If
Set tarRng = Nothing
Set srcRng = Nothing
Set srcSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Below is a screen cap of Shtemp1 ...

[image]

... and a screen cap of Shtemp2 ...

[image]

When "temp1" is typed into Cell A1 of the worksheet with the code attached, you get this ...

[image]

... changing Cell A1 to "temp2", you get this ...

[image]